# int 10h 13h bios string output not working

Tags: nasm, x86-16, bootloader, bios

i am using nasm and this is my code :

```
org 0x7c00
bits    16



section .data
 zeichen    dw  'hello2'
section .text


 mov ax,0x7c00
 mov    es,ax
 mov    bh,0
 mov    bp,zeichen

 mov    ah,13h
 mov    bl,00h
 mov    al,1
 mov    cx,6
 mov    dh,010h
 mov    dl,01h

int 10h

 jmp    $

 times  510 - ($-$$)    hlt
 dw 0xaa55
```

it does put the cursor on the right position but it prints nothing.
i load this file with qemu-system-i386.
The int10 ah=13h is a string output and in register es:bp has to be the address of the string

Comment: More than one issue. You'll have to get a better understanding of segment:offset addressing, but a bootloader is loaded at physical address 0x07c00. You have to pick an ORG and segment that equals that address. If you pick ORG 0x7c00 then you need to set the segments (_ES_ in this case) to zero since (0x0000<<4)+0x7c00 = 0x07c00 (physical address). You are loading _ES_ with 0x7c00 which is incorrect for the _ORG_ you chose.

Comment: Secondly when using `-f bin` _NASM_ output you don't want to use a `.data` section. Place the data inside the `text` section right after the code but before the boot signature.if you use `section data`  NASM will actually place your data after byte 512 outside the boot sector.

Comment: You set _BL_ to 0x00 . That is black on black so won't appear to output. Try 0x07 maybe?

Comment: Lastly. I think you meant to use `db` instead of `dw` since you have a string of characters. Change `zeichen    dw  'hello2'` to `zeichen    db  'hello2'`

Comment: Thanks for the nice help its working

Comment: can you please post the updated code that works. I move message to below the jump statement; I changed `mov bl,00h` to `mov bl, 7h` but it's just showing a black screen with cursor moved to roughly the middle of the screen. EDIT: it works, needed to also change `mov ax, 0x7c00` to `xor ax, ax`.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, since i have been trying to get this working for a long time now, here is a working version!

```
    org 0x7c00
    bits 16

    xor ax, ax
    mov es, ax
    xor bh, bh
    mov bp, msg

    mov ah, 0x13
    mov bl, [foreground]
    mov al, 1
    mov cx, [msg_length]
    mov dh, [msg_y]
    mov dl, [msg_x]

    int 0x10

    hlt

foreground dw 0xa 
msg db 'Hello, World!'
msg_length dw $-msg
msg_x dw 5
msg_y dw 2

    times  510 - ($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xaa55
```

here is a version closest to original.

```
    org 0x7c00
    bits 16

    ; video page number.
    mov bh, 0     
    ; ES:BP is the pointer to string.
    mov ax, 0x0
    mov es, ax    
    mov bp, msg   

    ; attribute(7 is light gray).
    mov bl, 0x7
    ; write mode: character only, cursor moved.
    mov al, 1
    ; string length, hardcoded.
    mov cx, 6
    ; y coordinate
    mov dh, 16
    ; x coordinate
    mov dl, 1

    ; int 10, 13
    mov ah, 0x13
    int 0x10

    ; keep jumping until shutdown.
    jmp $

msg dw  'hello2'

    times  510 - ($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: `msg_length dw $-msg` - normally you'd want to use an EQU constant as an immediate, not actually load the length from memory.

Comment: idk but if it still works it serves my purpose, since I definitely don't remember this anymore and it took me a bunch of trial and error making boot isos and running them in virtualbox to make sure I was honest. :/ But I'm sure  there must be some way to do it with an equ as well. In this example I wanted to use this as an opportunity to practice using memory access without crashing the virtualbox.

Comment: Yeah, it works, but it's a waste of space.  The instruction loading it needs a 2-byte absolute address, when it might as well have just used the 2-byte immediate directly, like `mov cx, msg_length` from an `equ`.  It doesn't need to be changeable at run-time, so you normally want to treat it like a C++ `constexpr size_t len = sizeof(msg);` instead of a `static size_t len = sizeof(msg);`